# Error al recibir información de un JSON en swift 3

Tags: php, json, webservice, ios, swift3

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación que debe conectarse a un web Service enviando dos parámetros para poder hacer la consulta a mysql, en web funciona perfecto, el problema es cuando quiero recuperar la información devuelta en mi aplicación, tengo un action creado donde ejecuto mi webservice con el siguiente bloque de código:

```
//Conexion con WebService

        let urlPath = URL(string: "http://sitioWeb.org.mx/webserv/lista.php?dato1=\(userEmail)&dato2=\(userPass)")

        let url = URLRequest(url: urlPath!)
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url){data, response, error in

            if(error != nil){
                //Si hay error se imprimiera en consola
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }

            let nsdata: NSData = NSData(data: data!)

            self.recuperarClimaDeJson(nsdata: nsdata)
        }

        task.resume()
```

Hasta esa parte no tengo ningún problema, cuando mando a llamar a mi función recuperarClimaDeJson se ejecuta el siguiente bloque de código:

```
func recuperarClimaDeJson(nsdata:NSData){

        do{
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: nsdata as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: String]

            //Hasta aqui funciona
            //print(jsonData)

            let arregloJsonEvento = jsonData?["evento"]

            if let jsonArray = arregloJsonEvento as? NSArray{

                jsonArray.enumerateObjects({model, index, stop in

                    let evento = model["nombreEvento"] as String
                    print(evento)
                });

            }

        }catch{
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

Pero me da estos dos errores:

el primer warning que me muestra es este:

> Cast from 'String?' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fail

este warning me lo da en esta linea:

```
if let jsonArray = arregloJsonEvento as? NSArray
```

y el segundo error que tengo es este:

> Type'Any' has no subscript members

en esta linea de código:

```
let evento = model["nombreEvento"] as String
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como viene tu JSON? tal vez lo estas parseando mal, podrias parsear mas informacion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, creas tu jsonData como tipo diccionario de key tipo String and value tipo String con la siguiente linea

```
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: nsdata as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: String]
```

Luego, cuando intentas hacer esta línea

```
let arregloJsonEvento = jsonData?["evento"]
if let jsonArray = arregloJsonEvento as? NSArray
```

Te marca el warning porque en la línea anterior, obtienes un valor de tu jsonData, pero este es de tipo [String: String] por ende Xcode deduce que arregloJsonEvento es de tipo String y tu intentas hacerle cast a NSArray

Luego el segundo error

```
let evento = model["nombreEvento"] as String
```

Aqui te marca

> Type'Any' has no subscript members

Porque model es de tipo string, los subscript solo funcionen en objetos de tipo Array o Diccionario, por ende al ser String no detecta los subscript members.

Para poder ayudarte tendrías que poner tu json pero puedes intentar lo siguiente:

Reemplaza la siguiente línea:

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: nsdata as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: String]
```

Con esta:

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: nsdata as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
```

Aquí estas especificando que la key es de tipo String y el valor puede ser de cualquier tipo(Entero, Diccionario, Arreglo, etc), por ende quitará el warning.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la ayuda, me funciono tu método pero tuve que cambiar la linea que mencionaste por que me marcaba un error, ya pude recibir mi información de forma correcta y mostrarla, muchas gracias